# Where to store images in server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, filesystems, webserver, server

According to my researches I've encountered three different places to store files for a webserver.

- Database
- Filesystem
- Amazon S3

Storing in databases is [not recommended.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay) Between the selection of filesystem and Amazon S3 what are the ups and downs of them?

Main points I consider is technical difficulty(time), scalability.

Answer (score 1):

As noted, databases aren't usually well suited for image storage.

Whether to use the filesystem or Amazon S3 probably depends on the nature of your application and images.  If the images are common to the application (such as design images) and can be deployed with every instance without requiring synchronization, they can stay in the filesystem.   If the images are shared, it might be better to store them on S3 so they can be accessed and maintained by multiple instances.

Providing a mechanism to access the images for maintenance should be considered as well.

Comment: By `images are shared` do you mean user provided images like profile picture?

Comment: Yes - any content that isn't part of the design.  For example a logo would probably be a design image, but a profile picture would be a content image.